# ionic proxy setting is not working properly , its taking too long time for downlaod and extract

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, proxy

I am new in ionic. At starting everything was working fine then suddenly it was asking for proxy server setting. Now i did all possible things, now its not asking for proxy server setting but download and extracting not working. its taking too long time but never completed.

I already tryd these codes.
$ npm install -g @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy

$ cd myProject # cd into your project's directory
$ npm install --save-exact --save-dev @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy

$ npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8888
$ npm config set https-proxy https://proxy.company.com:8888

This is showing on my CMD for 3 hours. 
C:\ionic>ionic start bh blank
√ Preparing directory .\bh - done!
/ Downloading and extracting blank starter

can any one suggest me exactly what i did wrong. Thank you

Comment: Your proxy configuration is maybe not good.

Comment: i used http://stimuluscloud.com:8888

Comment: is it correct pattern?